# What is the balanced chemical equation for a redox reaction between a lithium-cobalt battery and a graphite electrode?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, electrochemistry, redox

I'm doing a project for my last year of secondary school on lithium cobalt batteries and got confused about the equation.

This is the only equation I can find (source: [www.science.org.au](https://www.science.org.au/curious/technology-future/lithium-ion-batteries)):

\begin{align}
\ce{LiC6 &→ $x$ Li+ + $x$ e- + C6}\tag{anode}\\
\ce{Li_{(1−x)}CoO2 + $x$ Li+ + $x$ e- &→ LiCoO2}\tag{cathode}\\
\hline
\ce{C6 + LiCoO2 &→ Li_xC6 + Li_{(1−x)}CoO2}\\
\end{align}

But I don't understand it at all! I figured it must be balanced, but the '$x$' part of the equation is beyond my level of understanding. Is there a simpler way of writing this formula for someone at my level? If not, can someone please explain what this equation means?

Comment: Related, if not a duplicate: [What does x mean in (1-x)A – xB composite materials, molar ratio, weight ratio or volume fraction?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/109422/what-does-x-mean-in-1-xa-xb-composite-materials-molar-ratio-weight-ratio-o)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below we have a simpler way of the $\ce{Li-Co}$ cell reactions.

**Cathode half-reaction:**

$$\ce{CoO2 + Li+ + e- <=> LiCoO2}$$

**Anode half-reaction:**

$$\ce{LiC6 <=> C6 + Li+ + e-}$$

**Net-cell reaction:**

$$\ce{LiC6 + CoO2 <=> C6 + LiCoO2}$$

Over-discharging supersaturates lithium cobalt oxide, leading to the production of lithium oxide.

$$\ce{Li+ + e- + LiCoO2 -> Li2O + CoO}$$

Similarly overcharging (up to $\pu{5.2 V}$) leads to following reaction:

$$\ce{LiCoO2 -> Li+ + CoO2 + e-}$$

Comment: At overcharging, there also occurs deposition of metallic lithium and its reaction with the dialkylcarbonate solvent. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/la980454y